# How to "display the list in correct position even the page is scrolled"

Tags: html, css, css-position

1. As I'm new to react , I don't know much about positioning.
2. In my page I have a Settings icon, when I click that icon a list box appears at the bottom of the icon.
3. when I don't scroll-down the page and click the icon , the list box  appears correctly at the bottom of the icon.
4. when I scroll-down the page and click the icon , the list box  appears the bottom of the page.
5. The code :

```html
    top: 657px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 853.234px;
    right: auto;
```

[image: After Scroll-down]

[image: Before Scroll-down]

Comment: We can't say much about this without seeing any code. Only thing that we can say is: Don't use absolute positioning.

Comment: Please add a screenshot for more details.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot @ Sunny Vaghadia  @ cloned

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning, instead use relative. provide us with more codes via stack snippet or codePen.